# Get the difference between two dates in hours

Tags: scala, jodatime

I'm trying to calculate the hour difference between two `joda` dates.

```
val d1 = getDateTime1()
val d2 = getDateTime2()
```

Here is what I did:

```
# attemp1
val hours = Hours.hoursBetween(d1, d2) // error - types mismatch

# attempt2
val p = Period(d1, d2, PeriodType.hours()) // error - there is such a constructor
p.getHours
```

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `getDateTime1` should be `org.joda.time.DateTime`.

This woks fine:

```
val d1: org.joda.time.DateTime = DateTime.now
val d2: org.joda.time.DateTime = DateTime.nextMonth

val hours = Hours.hoursBetween(d1, d2)
// org.joda.time.Hours = PT672H
```

There is no factory method `apply` for `Period`, you should use `new` to create `Period`:

```
val p = new Period(d1, d2, PeriodType.hours())
// org.joda.time.Period = PT672H
```

If you are using [nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) you could also use method `to` to get `Interval` and than convert it to `Period`:

```
d1 to d2 toPeriod PeriodType.hours
// org.joda.time.Period = PT672H

(d1 to d2).duration.getStandardHours
// Long = 672
```

Also try `sbt clean`.

Comment: d1 and d2 are not ReadableInstant

Comment: actually, `val d1: org.joda.time.DateTime = DateTime.now()` - does work but `val d1 = DateTime.now()` doesn't. The types are the same - joda DateTime.

Comment: @Alex: try `sbt clean`, also show your `build.sbt` - looks like you have 2 different classes with the same name `DateTime`.