# Date difference in scala

Tags: scala, date

I need a function to find the difference(in number of days)between two dates in "yyyy-mm-dd" format.

```
val basedate = "1970-01-01"
val currdate = "2015-02-25"
val diff = currdate - basedate
```

Please suggest.

Comment: here is the proper answer ,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508168/get-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-hours

Answer (score 9):

i think You are searching something like this

```
import java.time.LocalDate 
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
```

---

```
val startDate = "1970-01-01" 
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
val oldDate = LocalDate.parse(startDate, formatter)
val currentDate = "2015-02-25"
val newDate = LocalDate.parse(currentDate, formatter)
println(newDate.toEpochDay() - oldDate.toEpochDay())
```

Comment: I am unable to import the packages. Guess its valid for jdk8 whereas I am using 7. Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: @KundanKumar, You can use JodaTime API [http://www.joda.org/joda-time/]. Java8 time api is taken from Joda Time only. The syntax will be almost similar between java time api and joda api.

Comment: @KundanKumar Or use http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/ to avoid migration later.