# scala get difference between two dates in number of days

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was trying to calculate the number of days between 2 dates in scala. I tried using `compareTo` and `import java.time.Period` function. But it is not giving the exact value of days when comparing two dates from different months.

```
val date1 = "2022-04-01"
date1: String = 2022-04-01

val date2 = "2022-04-04"
date2: String = 2022-04-04

date2.compareTo(date1)
res37: Int = 3

val date2 = "2022-05-04"
date2: String = 2022-05-04

date2.compareTo(date1)
res38: Int = 1
```

```
val date1 = LocalDate.parse("2022-04-01")
date1: java.time.LocalDate = 2022-04-01

val date2 = LocalDate.parse("2022-04-04")
date1: java.time.LocalDate = 2022-04-04

val p = Period.between(date1, date2)
p: java.time.Period = P3D

p.getDays
res39: Int = 3

val date2 = LocalDate.parse("2022-05-04")
date2: java.time.LocalDate = 2022-05-04

val p = Period.between(date1, date2)
p: java.time.Period = P1M3D

p.getDays
res40: Int = 3
```

I want to get the difference as 33 days while comparing the dates `2022-04-01` and `2022-05-04`. Is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date difference in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718644/date-difference-in-scala)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [`LocalDate.until()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method with unit set to `ChronoUnit.DAYS`:

```scala
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

val date1 = LocalDate.parse("2022-04-01")
val date2 = LocalDate.parse("2022-05-03")

val daysBetween = date1.until(date2, ChronoUnit.DAYS)

// scala> date1.until(date2, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
// res1: Long = 32
```

Note that your first attempt does simple lexicographical string comparison which is oblivious to the fact that your strings are dates. The return value of `String.compareTo()` (and `Comparable<T>.compareTo()` in general) is to be interpreted only on the basis whether it is 0, < 0, or > 0. The actual value is meaningless in most cases. The fact that it matches the actual number of days in your first example is due to how your dates are formatted and to how `String.compareTo()` works:

> In this case, `compareTo` returns the difference of the two character values at position *k* in the two string *[sic]*

Here, *k* refers to the position where the two strings first differ.

Your second attempt with `Period` doesn't work either because `Period` represents conceptual differences. Adding `P1M3D` to some date means incrementing the month by one and the day by three, therefore the length in days is dependent on the month to which it is being applied:

```
2022-04-01 + P1M3D = 2022-05-04 -> 33 days
2022-05-01 + P1M3D = 2022-06-04 -> 34 days
```

Thus, a freestanding `Period` object has no length in days (unless it only has days but not months or years) and the `getDays` accessor returns only the days component, not the full number of days.